# Qt4 - преобразовение массива типа char в QString

Tags: qt, c++

Есть функция, заполняющая предоставлнный массив *char buffer[255]* данными, полученными с COM-порта. Требуется скопировать их в переменную *QString a*, а потом вывести в *ui.text*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

QString(buffer);
если заканчивается '\0', иначе - 
QString(QByteArray(buffer, 255));

Comment: Спасибо, я после бейсика лечусь... А как в TextBox вывести этот QString?

Comment: Что есть "TextBox"? В Qt нет такого контрола

Comment: а в бейсике есть =)

Comment: 1. простой однострочный редактор QLineEdit (метод для установки текста setText("text"));
2. многострочный редактор - QTextEdit (setText("text, <i>html</i>"), setHtml("<b>text</b>"), setPlainText("text")).